# Ionic 4 and Electron - 2 way binding giving error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, electron

**Brief Description:** I am using Ionic 4 and Electron. I have used a simple code in my `partym.page.html` as shown below:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Name1</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name1"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

If I do `ionic serve` everything works as expected, but if I do `ng build --prod && electron .` it throws me error, pasting it below

```
ERROR in src/app/partym/partym.page.html(12,32): : Property 'name1' does not exist on type 'PartymPage'.
src/app/partym/partym.page.html(12,32): : Property 'name1' does not exist on type 'PartymPage'.
```

FYI, **FormsModule** is already imported in `app.module.ts` , called in imports and also included in `partym.module.ts`

### Edit 1

I have defined `name1` in `home.page.ts`

```
export class PartymPage implements OnInit {
  name1;
```

Comment: have you defined `name1` in your component.ts file?

Answer (score 2):

You should initialise a variable before using it in the template -

partym.page.ts

```
export class PartymComponent implements OnInit {
  name1: any;
```